# Error compiling Query with JPA (EL) and Enum

Tags: jpa, enums, eclipselink

I have a weird problem with JPA (EclipseLink 2.3.2) and Enum in a Named Query.

I have a named query:

`SELECT f FROM FILES f WHERE (:dataType IS NULL OR f.dataType = :dataType)`

which results in

`Error compiling the query ... invalid enum equal expression, cannot compare enum value of type [com.example.DataTypeEnum} with a non enum value of type [java.lang.Object]`

Now i thought i might do an invalid operation, but if i try

`SELECT f FROM FILES f WHERE (:dataType IS NULL)`

or

`SELECT f FROM FILES f WHERE (f.dataType = :dataType)`

or even

`SELECT f FROM FILES f WHERE (f.dataType = :dataType OR :dataType IS NULL)`

the query compiles and runs fine. (but obviously not with the desired result).

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

edit:

I have my entity annotated as such:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public DataTypeEnum getDataType() {
    return dataType;
}
```

Comment: `SELECT f FROM FILES f WHERE (f.dataType IS NULL OR f.dataType = :dataType)` try this? Also, please show code where you pass the parameter of :dataType.

Comment: that's not what i want to achieve. i want to check if the param is NULL (unset). Also I should have mentioned it's a named query, so i get the error when jpa tries to compile that. i'm not even trying to use it.

Comment: Why don't you check for null value at service, not DAO level? I think it is more appropriate.

Comment: I considered that, but i have 4 "filters" and would then need a named query for every permutation.

Comment: Why do you even need a named query? You could construct it with criteria builder, also then you could do some more checking, not only if the value you are passing is null.

Comment: i'm new to JPA and wanted to move the (DIY) query building away from the business logic. i'll take a look at the CB, but still, shouldn't my query work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12993/discussion-between-jmelnik-and-tobi-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is odd.  What version are you using?  Did you try 2.4?

Comment: EclipseLink 2.3.2 (Released Dec 9, 2011). No, didn't try 2.4 and don't see it on the official page. And I'd rather not use an 'experimental' build.